# Меню на ReplyKeyboard с одинаковыми кнопками (telebot)

Tags: telebot, клавиатура

Допустим есть стартовое меню:
-Пункт1
-Пункт2
-Пункт3

В каждом из этих пунктов есть:

- собственная кнопка "Продолжить", которая вызывает ещё одно меню с кнопками
- общая кнопка "Отмена", которая ведет обратно на стартовое меню.

С кнопкой "Отмена" всё понятно. А вот как через ReplyKeyboard реализовать "Продолжить", если во всех трех пунктах она своя собственная, но при этом имеет одинаковое название? Инлайн клавиатуру не предлагать.
Была идея как-то схитрить за счет добавления пробелов в название кнопки, но ничего не получилось(может быть из-за того, что мои познания совсем невелики)
Ещё нашел такую штуку, как register_next_step_handler, но ещё не разобрался как она работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не то чтобы это верное решение, я бы назвал это костылем, но тем не менее можно создать две "одинаковые" кнопки. Попробуйте заменить в слове `Пункт` русскую букву `У` (кириллица) на английскую `y` (латиница). Может букву `у` и будет видно, но думаю с буквами `а`, `o` должно сливаться, и обычный юзер не заметит разницы. Реального способа кроме метода `register_next_step_handler` я так и не нашел - но он имеет свои недостатки, чтобы использовать для такой задачи.

Пример рабочего костыля:

```
if message.text == 'Пункт1':
    return 'русская буква у'
elif message.text == 'Пyнкт1': # здесь str отличается от другого str в условии
    return 'Английская буква y'
```

Comment: хм, как-то сразу не сообразил что так можно было сделать. Но уже делаю через register_next_step_handler. Тем не менее - Спасибо за "костыль"